# 18.04 - Suspended system resumes with all applications closed (as if from fresh boot)

Tags: 18.04, suspend

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell i7559 notebook.

When the system is resumed from suspend, it fails to restore the state that the system was in prior to suspend. That is, there are no applications open and it's as if I had booted it after a shut down. This has been the case since I installed Ubuntu on this machine.

When the system is first placed into suspend, it seems to wake immediately on a splash screen (with notifications) for just a few seconds before suspending completely (screen, fans, periphery devices, etc. off). Perhaps this is a symptom of a separate issue?

As suggested in other answers elsewhere, I've updated my GRUB config like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

Unfortunately, this does **not** resolve the issue.

I have also updated to Linux kernel 4.18 (4.18.0-25-generic according to `uname -a`) as others have mentioned that there are several fixes in recent kernel releases that address suspend issues. Unfortunately, this also hasn't resolved my issue.

When reviewing `dmesg`, the latest messages occur well before the system went into suspend.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might go about fixing this?

Comment: I have noticed ubuntu 19.04 has solved this issue ... using either default nouveau or if machine has nvidia card using nvidia drivers as well

Answer (score 0):

If your applications don't come back, you did not successfully suspend.

How much RAM do you have? How much swap? `free -h` will show you. You need at least as much swap as RAM.

Read `man pm-is-supported` ("`pm`" stands for "Power Management", which handles Suspend/Resume/Hibernate/Wake).

Read `man pm-action` to see what scripts are run when your system changes power state.

All these commands are in the `pm-utils` package in Ubunu 16.04.6LTS.

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM and 3.8GB in swap available, which should be more than enough I think. `pm-is-supported` doesn't return a value for me and reading through `pm-action`, it doesn't seem like I have a suspend log available to look through at `/var/log/`.

Comment: `man pm-is-supported` says the result is returned as exit status - did you look at `$?`? You also must pick one of the options for `pm-is-supported`. How do you think 16GB of RAM can be saved in 3.8GB swap? You could `journalctl --since="-10 minutes"` shortly after resuming to see log messages.

Comment: Read `man` on all these: `sudo id;for i in suspend hibernate suspend-hybrid ; do  /bin/echo -n "$i is ";sudo pm-is-supported --$i;if [[ $? -eq 1 ]] ; then /bin/echo -n "NOT "; fi;/bin/echo "supported"; done`